# How to update a cloud service on Azure with a limited user account from the command line

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

The service I wish to upgrade is in a resource group and my user account is configured as an owner of that resource group. The user account is limited to only access the one resource group.

I can successfully update the cloud service using the new management portal by uploading a `cspkg` and a `cscfg` file.

I'm trying to automate this process using Azure Powershell.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -ServiceName test-service -Configuration C:\temp\test-service.cscfg -Package "https://test-service.blob.core.windows.net/azurepowershelldeploy/test-package.cspkg" -Slot Production -Mode Auto -Label test-2015-07-28T00:33:04

ForbiddenError: The server failed to authenticate the request.
Verify that the certificate is valid and is associated with this subscription.
```

Having a look in fiddler, it's making a request to this endpoint, and getting back a 403 forbidden.

```
POST /xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx/services/hostedservices/test-service/deploymentslots/Production/?comp=upgrade HTTP/1.1
```

I believe the ASM API's don't work properly with resource groups. Is there a method to update a cloud service using the new ARM API's?

Comment: How do you set the credentials? Does Get-AzureDeployment work with that?

Comment: Are you even an adminstrator on that subscription and connected?

Comment: @jisaak I use Add-AzureAccount to set my credentials.

Comment: @JamesWoolfenden As I stated this account is NOT an administrator of the subscription, it is a limited account, it is however an owner of the resource group that contains the service and can deploy the service from the portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy, update or delete all of the resources for your application in a single, coordinated operation using ARM.

You would redeploy your ARM template to an existing RG using:[New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn654593.aspx)

> The New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet adds a deployment to an existing resource group, including the resources that the deployment needs. This cmdlet is similar to the New-AzureResourceGroup cmdlet, but it works on existing resource groups, instead of new ones. To add a single resource to a resource group, use the New-AzureResource cmdlet.

A good walk through for your scenario (with a few changes) is at: [Provision and deploy microservices predictably in Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-deploy-complex-application-predictably/)

> This tutorial shows how to provision and deploy an application composed of microservices in Azure App Service as a single unit and in a predictable manner using JSON resource group templates and PowerShell scripting.

Instead of using an app service resource in the RG template, use the types of resources you'd need. Then call the above New-AzureResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet instead of New-AzureResourceGroup cmdlet.

Comment: My understanding of deploying with ARM is that you can use it to predictably deploy the same infrastructure repeatably (prod,dev,test) but it's not the mechanism used for updating the code in the deployment.

We already use ARM to deploy the infrastructure but I wan't to run the update operation on a single .NET cloud service.